# Facebook api. How I can get all nottagged photo my Profile?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photo

How do I get the photos as a page in facebook that are not tagged?

```
$feedURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $this->user . "/albums?access_token=" . $this->access_token;
$albumData = json_decode(file_get_contents($feedURL));

foreach ($albumData->data as $album) {
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $album->id . "/photos?access_token=" . $this->access_token;
    $photo = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    foreach ($photo->data as $_) {
        // Here I do not know how to identify the not tagged photos
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? Please show us your attempts.

Comment: I think getting all the photos from all the albums, and by trying to search for those that do not have tags, but may have a more elegant way?

Comment: Can anybody help or suggest another solution?